# Disable click in DataGridvIew

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a DataGridView 'DGV' that is set to readonly via the properties panel. My question is, why if the DGV is set to readonly, users are able to click within the grid? I thought that by setting a grid to readonly, it removed this function.

I have tried various ways to disable any clicks in the grid but no luck. Can anyone shed some light on how to make the grid strictly read only with no user interaction allowed. Thanks

Things I have tried at both after the grid has loaded and before.

```
DGV.ReadOnly = True
DGV.ClearSelection()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadOnly property has nothing to do with the possibility of clicking it. It just means that you can't edit its cells.

I suggest disabling the selection completely handling the `SelectionChanged` event

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```

and also setting the `DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False`

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Set
`datagridview.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` to same value as `.BackColor`
and `datagridview.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor` to same value as `.ForeColor`

Then user cannot notice if it was clicked...

Comment: I am using alternating row colors, so I don't think that would work. Thanks

Comment: Just do same things for `datagridview.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor` ...

Comment: I call shenanigans!